# Java JMS mix messaging implementations

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

Is it possible to use java messaging with mixed implementations.

E.g.: Is it possible to connect an ActiveMQ client **directly** to an MQSeries(IBM) server to read/write messages from/to the message queue?

Comment: The question is not amply clear , what is meant by mixing implementations ? You can have a "bridge" application that can take messages from AMQ and post to WMQ and vice versa. IBM's SIB JMS can be integrated with WMQ directly through configuration of buses for example. Broad chances are you cannot mix 2 messaging providers directly , but can keep transporting messages between them using applications

Comment: @Ramachandran G A Thanks for your suggestions. The message refers to to a direct connection between an activemq client and an WMQ server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is an API specification, not a wire format specification. JMS describes the signature of APIs. It does not say how the internals should be implemented. Hence JMS client library implementations are Messaging Provider specific.

A IBM MQ JMS Client knows how (i.e wire format) to communicate  with IBM MQ. Similarly Active MQ JMS client knows how to speak to Active MQ JMS provider. Since the implementations are different, Active MQ JMS Client will not be communicate with IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

no, each client implementation is specific to broker, maybe only with client for amqp protocol if supported

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the standardized wire protocols that both brokers support-- AMQP and MQTT, but as previous commenters noted it is not possible with JMS.