# Multiple ways to configure MQ or ActiveMQ Listener

Tags: spring, ejb, jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

Can someone explain different ways of configuring message listener.
I know two ways:

1. Spring Jms Listener
2. EJB MDB way.

Are there any other ways (should be applicable to both IBM MQ and Active MQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, your proposed ways are good ones with [Camel JMS](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html).

For the second question take a look at [Java JMS mix messaging implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507846/java-jms-mix-messaging-implementations)

if you want to use the same client without changing anything you have to use AMQP ptotocol wich is designed for this.

here is 2 examples :
[ActiveMQ AMQP with JMS transformer leveraging spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554135/activemq-amqp-with-jms-transformer-leveraging-spring-integration/41566982#41566982)
[Unable to access ActiveMQ using JMS based code and amqp 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528325/unable-to-access-activemq-using-jms-based-code-and-amqp-1-0/39529196#39529196)